# How to get a date & time in (MM/dd/yyyy hh:MM a) format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsdate

In my app I have to show  Date & Time Like this,

> 10/19/2011 3pm

Currently I write this code,

```
NSDateFormatter *formatar=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];       
[formatar setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY   HH:mm a"];
[formatar setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *st=[formatar stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

But Getting date in this format:

> 10/19/2011 15.00

So, How can i get that in this **10/19/2011 3pm** Format?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to do some minor changes to the date format to make it work as you need.

1.Your date format should contain only the hour(single-digit) and no minutes.

```
"MM/dd/YYYY H a" // Still "a" wouldn't not work here
```

2.The hour should be in *12 hour format* ie., *"h"* not *"H"* in order for *"a"* to work. Finally, remove the space between *"h"* and *"a"*.

```
"MM/dd/YYYY ha" // Now you will get what you want!
```